# How to change a form input text to uppercase using a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input, uppercase

I'm trying to change a form input field (username) to uppercase and to remove all spaces within the text. I know there are a few ways one could do this but I need to figure out how to do this using a function. I need to get the input by it's id and use the toUpperCase method but I cannot figure this out for the life of me. As you might be able to tell, I am new to JavaScript. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

HTML:

```
<div class="login-form">
                <h1 class="h1-login">Welcome</h1>
                <h4>Please login to enjoy our services</h4>

                <form class="login-form" name="login-form" method="post">

                    <label for="username"><span class="required">*</span>Username:</label>
                        <input id="username" type="text" name="username" autofocus onkeyup="changeToUpperCase()">
                    <label for="password"><span class="required">*</span>Password:</label>
                        <input type="password" name="password" size="8" maxlength="8">

                    <input class="login" type="submit" value="Login">

                </form>

            </div>
```

Here is the JavaScript:

```
function changeToUpperCase() {
document.login-form.value = document.login-form.value.toUpperCase();
}
```

This code does not work... and I have no idea how to remove spaces from an input text. Please help me.

Comment: The `-` in `document.login-form` is subtraction.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Just a friendly note from the harried people who read through questions on their free time.  "Does not work" is the least useful thing you say when asking a question.  It is far better to say what you *expect* to happen and what is *actually* happening.

Comment: I will keep this in mind for future questions, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd change the html to this:

```
onkeyup="changeToUpperCase(this)"
```

And adjust the function to this

```
function changeToUpperCase(t) {
   var eleVal = document.getElementById(t.id);
   eleVal.value= eleVal.value.toUpperCase().replace(/ /g,'');
}
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/pibaquri/2/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: I used the code that you suggested and it work. Hallelujah! I also need to remove any spaces that may be present in the username field. I see @adrichman posted a solution but cannot get it to work.

Comment: @DavidBarnes: Cool I just updated is to remove the white spaces. Didn't see that requirement.

Comment: thanks. I still do not completely understand what the code is doing but I'm glad it works. I know the function creates a variable and then makes it equal to the id using the getElementsById method. It then sets the elements value to uppercase and uses a replace method to remove white spaces, although I'm not sure what (/ /g,'') represents. It would be awesome, if you have the time, to explain this function. I know it would help me in the future. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @DavidBarnes: No probs, basically .replace() is a method of the String object in Javascript, it accepts 2 parameters, the first can either be a string or regular expression, and the 2nd is what you would like to replace it with. So in this case I used a regular expression that basically says look for all spaces, inclusive of tabs, single, double spaces etc which is this '/ /' and the 'g' specifies to do a global match. The second parameter is the '' which is just an empty string. Hope this explains it a bit better?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
 onkeyup="changeToUpperCase(this)"
```

Then in the script:

```
function changeToUpperCase(el)
 {
     el.value =el.value.trim().toUpperCase();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using this:

```
('text with spaces').replace(" ", "");
```

Comment: Sorry to be a nuisance but, can you elaborate on this? How would I implement this line of code in the context of my script?

Answer (score 0):

```
function changeToUpperCase() {
    document.getElementById("username").value = document.getElementById("username").value.toUpperCase().replace(" ", "")
}
```

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/haxtbh/DDrCc/

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
function trimAndUpper(id){
    var element = document.getElementById(id);
    element.value= element.value.trim().toUpperCase();
}
```

Add the trim function to a String:

```
String.prototype.trim = function () {
    return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
  };
```

Usage:
[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wyuRB/)

BTW using str.Replace isn't good. This will replace the first occurance only.