# Converting Input text from lowercase to uppercase and vice versa in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/JSUpperLower.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


    <input type="text" name="" id="upper">

    <input type="text" name="" id="lower">
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
function lowerupper()
{
    var str = document.getElementById('upper').value;
    // var lowertoupper = str.toUpperCase();

    if(str == str.toLowerCase())
    {
        document.getElementById('upper').value = str.toUpperCase();

    }


}
```

I want the text I type in my input text to change in realtime, I'm relatively new to js. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Look into the keypress event, and add it to your input elements.

Comment: When you searched for how to make input upper or lowercase while typing what did you find?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23172006/how-to-change-a-form-input-text-to-uppercase-using-a-javascript-function

Comment: @RyanWilson Thanks, this solved my issue for the most part, can you tell me the proper if condition for doing this? it works without if tho.

Comment: @Gaurav Depending on how you are attaching the keypress event, since i don't have the code to go on, I would check to see if the object which raised the event has id of 'upper' and if so, set the value toUpperCase() otherwise set it toLowerCase()

Comment: @RyanWilson Thanks, will look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it go go to upper use the keypress event like this.

```js
function lowerupper(){
         var str = document.getElementById('upper').value   
        document.getElementById('upper').value = str.toUpperCase();
         var s = document.getElementById('lower').value   
        document.getElementById('lower').value = s.toLowerCase();
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeypress="lowerupper();" id="upper">
    <input type="text" onkeypress="lowerupper();" id="lower">
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry that I'm not correct answer on your question, but I use Jquery to convert input text from lowercase to uppercase.

> Jquery

```
    $(function() {
    $('#upper').keyup(function() {
        this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();
    });
});
```

> HTML

```
  <input type="text" name="up" id="upper">
  <input type="text" name="down" id="lower">
```

Answer (score 0):

function upper(ustr) {

```
        var ustr = document.getElementById("Your textbox id ").value;
        var res = ustr.toUpperCase();
        document.getElementById("txtempid").value = res;
    }
```

if required use onblur instead of onkey press event

Answer (score -2):

Just put `style="text-transform:uppercase"` in your input tag for uppercase
and for lowercase put `style="text-transform:lowercase"`

Uppercase : `<input type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" />`
Lowercase : `<input type="text" style="text-transform:lowercase" />`

Comment: Seeing the question was `Converting Input text from lowercase to uppercase and vice versa in **Javascript**` you should include at least a solution using JavaScript as OP might have to use JavaScript. Though suggesting a CSS only solution is a great **addition**

Comment: Using style will only display the text correctly but the value would be same like entered. Not doing down vote bcz question doesnt talk about value.

Comment: @Uzair no problem.